# Does the simulated turtlebot in gazebo require calibration?

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot-gazebo, turtlebot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to know if turtlebot which is simulated in gazebo requires calibration of Odometry and Gyro.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12706/does-the-simulated-turtlebot-in-gazebo-require-calibration?/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Calibration is not required, but note in simulation there's numerical errors associated with physics calculation causing the robot odometry to drift a bit as the robot drives around.  The numerical error is associated with the time step size and the inner iteration steps setting if quickstep is used.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1